# Dll downlad Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, taxonomy, download, dll-embedding

Where can I download Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll for SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is available as [NuGet-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy/15.0.0). It contains version 15.0.4420.1017 which is also shipped with SharePoint 2010.

[image: SharePoint 2010]

Comment: This is for SP 2013. I need version 14.0

Comment: I have checked before answering. This version is delivered in my SharePoint 2010 system, even if it tells "Version 15.0". I will add a screenshot to my answer.